# VB.NET Why won't my Function return an array?

Tags: vb.net, function, return-type

I'm trying to write a function that returns an Array that I can pass into a String.Format:

```
Public Function ToArray() As Array
    Dim vals As New ArrayList()
    vals.Add(Me("district"))
    vals.Add(Me("county"))
    vals.Add(Me("route"))
    vals.Add(Me("section"))
    vals.Add(Me("beg_logmile"))
    vals.Add(Me("end_logmile"))
    vals.Add(Me("date_logged"))
    vals.Add(Me("year_installed").year())
    vals.Add(Me("document"))
    Return vals.ToArray()
End Function

Public Overrides Function toString() As String
    Return String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4:f3} {5:f3} {6} {7} {8}", Me.ToArray())
End Function
```

The above does not work. I've converted it to just String.Format("{0}", Me.ToArray()) and it tells me that I've got a System.Object[]

I haven't been able to find an answer yet on Google or SO, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your function declaration to this:

```
Public Function ToArray() As Object()
```

The `ToString()` overload you are using expects an array of objects, not an instance of the `Array` class.

Answer (score 2):

Your function should look like this:

```
Public Function ToArray() As Object()
    Return New Object() {Me("district"), Me("county"), Me("route"), ... ,Me("document") }
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your definition:

Public Overrides Function toString() As String()